# WSEACCES error binding to socket on Windows Server 2008

Tags: sockets, tcp, bind, winsock

I have a windows server 2008 machine on which I am unable to bind to a socket at a particular high-port range without getting an error 10013 (WSAEACCES).  In particular, I can't bind to ports 62788-64764, which is rather inconvenient since I'm trying to start up a service that is configured to run on ports in that range, and I can't change that configuration.  The process is launched from a cmd window having Administrator privileges.-a

Why can't I bind to these port numbers?

I've tried all the obvious things:

Netstat -a does not show any processes listening on those ports.

Using netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp, I verified that there aren't any excluded ports in this range:

Start Port    End Port
----------    --------
        80          80
       443         443
      8172        8172
     47001       47001

The machine was running a DNS server, so I set the DNS SocketPoolSize to zero, but that didn't work.  (I even shut the server down, but that didn't help either).

I've rebooted (and kicked) the machine several times, and I've reset the winsock catalog (netsh winsock reset).

There's got to be some other configuration setting I am missing; any ideas?

UPDATE:  I discovered that shutting down the Windows service "Internet Connection Sharing" makes the problem go away, although why that service was locking up these specific ports is still unclear to me.

Comment: It's a permission problem, not 'port in use'.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what could be impacting the permissions in this narrow range?  According to the MS documentation, this error can be returned if another process has the socket bound with SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE, or if the socket is accessed in a way contrary to the socket's access permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess with ICS enabled, Hide NAT is also enabled (internal IPs hiding behind a single - or multiple - external IPs). That means the Server will need to rewrite source IP and source port of clients going to the internet to avoid source port collisions.
Hiding NAT gateways thus usually reserve a port range in the higher area (>port 50000) for that. So ICS may block a whole range of high ports for NAT porposes.

And this is why server applications should stay in the low / privileged range of ports (i.e. <1024)